# PHP Ternary Operator not working as expected

Tags: php

I know there are countless articles out there to read about php ternary operators, however, I have read a bunch but cannot get it to work.

This is my code without ternary operators:

```
    if ( get_field('fs_ski_resort_data_fs_name') != null && !empty(get_field('fs_ski_resort_data_fs_name') ) )
    {
        $the_name = get_field('fs_ski_resort_data_fs_name');
    } else  {
        $the_name = get_field('fs_ski_resort_data_osm_name');
    }   
    echo 'The name'.$the_name;
```

The above works, however, is the below doesn't produce the same result as above.

```
    $the_name = get_field('fs_ski_resort_data_fs_name') ?? $the_name = get_field('fs_ski_resort_data_osm_name');
    echo $the_name;
```

Please tell me my mistake.

Comment: `??` only checks if the value is `null`, not if it's empty. So the two codes aren't equivalent. Use `?:` instead.

Comment: And in the first code, you only need to check `!empty()`, since null is empty.

Comment: Also for terms, the `??` is `null coalescing` and `?:` is ternary.